# can't see the result after i update a row in a table in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Peace!
i created a gridview and ive bended the data using a ObjectDataSource,
for some reasons i created the CRUD methods to do the work instead of using the CRUD method generated by the LINQDataSource; everything is just working fine but the update method,
when i update a row in my gridview everything become as if there isnt any update!
but when i check the database i can see that the rows is been updated!
i can't find a solution (yet) to this issue.
i'am using the updatepanel to have the autopostback without refreshing the page.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!
well in my case all i had to do is to instantiate another instance of my DataContext :S
i've been using the a static DataContext.
cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you rebind the GridView after you perform the update?

Comment: thanks though 
yes i've just googled this suggestion (question) and i tried the following code lines:
 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // Set "initial" query parameters, then ...
            BindData();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        BindData();
    }
    private void BindData()
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
but no results :S